# combining two slow motion videos in split screen

Tags: video-sequence-editor

I have used the speed control effect to slow down two videos. Now I want to show the slow motion versions simultaneously in a split screen.

I am able to create the split screen using the transform effect on the original videos, but not on the slow motion videos. Any tutorials available on how to do this?

Thanks,
Jigyasu.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use any effect strip (like speed control) same way like original videos. So, to get the transform effect over the speed control, select the Speed control strip and select **Add** -> **Effect strip**  ->  **Transform**. Or if you already have the Transform strip on original video, select the Speed control strip, then - Transform strip with <kbd>Shift</kbd> and then press <kbd>R</kbd> *(Reassign Input)*

[image]

Also you can group strips with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>G</kbd> and you can use this group like a usual video strip:

[image]

Comment: Thank you, it worked. I think my issue was that I was not stacking the effect strips properly. I had them stacked as: channel 0 <-> video 1, then channel 1 <-> speed for video 1, then channel 2 <-> video 2, then channel 3 <-> speed for video 2 and then channels 4 and 5 for the two transform strips and it wasn't working. Is this assessment correct that the stacking as described above will not work as I wanted it to?

Comment: The physical stacking will not make a difference and using Meta strips will remove any ambiguity around which effect strip is affecting which strip.

Comment: @JigyasuJuggler don't forget to change blend mode to **alpha over** for top transform strip (or use "alpha over" strip)